# Getting task creator in Asana API

Tags: asana

I'm building an Asana API wrapper in python and trying to add functionality to get the creator of a task. As per the suggestion in this question: [How to expose asana task creator?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15504779/how-to-expose-asana-task-creator) I'm loading the stories and inferring it from there but I assumed there'd be a story with the text 'created' as shows up in the web interface but the earliest story I see is always 'added to' then either a tag or project and there is no system story with the text 'created'

Is this the intended behavior of the API?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's actually not the API but the fact that there actually isn't an event for the task being created - we store the creator and the creation time on the task, so it's kind of redundant (and saves creating a new DB object for every task creation - at scale the little things can add up). In the UI, we show task creation information inline with the other stories, but for the API you should just get that info from the task data itself.

Comment: Ah. Is adding this as a task property on the roadmap?

Comment: Ah, you can actually request `created_by` via `opt_fields`. That field's not documented yet, but it should be soon! Note that if you use `opt_fields` you have to explicitly include all the fields you want, e.g. `GET /task/:id?opt_fields=name,created_at,created_by.name`