# How do you get the "author" of an Asana task from the API?

Tags: asana, asana-api

Trying to determine who created an Asana task from the API, but:

- There's no author field on the task itself.
- Followers cannot be used because the creator can remove himself from followers.
- Looking at the stories of a task, there is not system event for creation.

The best I've found is to use the `created_by` field of the first (eldest) story of a task.

Is there a better alternative?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Getting task creator in Asana API](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26997313/getting-task-creator-in-asana-api)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This field is not currently available on tasks, your approach (look at first story) is the best practice at the moment. We'll take this into consideration for future API improvements.